# Titanium button not changing background color when selected

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium

I have a newbie question: A simple button I've created in Titanium for iPhone refuses to change colors when clicked. Originally I used a button for this function; since it didn't work, I changed to a View, but neither works. Here it how it is set up:

```
var quifButton = Ti.UI.createView({  // tried this with createButton, as well
    top: 44, left: 5, width: 310, height: 42, 
    backgroundColor: '#333', 
    backgroundSelectedColor: '#fff', 
    backgroundFocusedColor: '#fff', 
    touchEnabled: true, 
    borderColor: BOR_DK, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 5 });
```

When I click the Button / View in the iPhone simulator, nothing happens. Any ideas why this doesn't work and how I can make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click is not same than focus. If you want to change color on click, you have to add eventlistener to button or view.

```
quifButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   quifButton.backgroundColor = '#fff';
});
```

***Edit:**

```
 backgroundSelectedColor: '#fff', 
 backgroundFocusedColor: '#fff',
```

These are not supported in iOS.

Comment: That's what he asked. How to change the color on click.

Comment: but when the button should be released the button should look in origin style.

Comment: He didn't say that in the question. He was talking only about click. BackgroundFocusedColor is not supported in iOS: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundFocusedColor

Comment: Hi Joonas,  Dhairya is right that I'm trying to see the background color changing only during a tap, but I appreciate your hint about backgroundFocusedColor not being supported. I guess I'll take the event listener route and listen for both tap and un-tap.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in iOS, and is not related to Titanium.

Try this instead for the behaviour you're looking for:

```
  someBtn.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { 
    someBtn.backgroundColor = 'green';
  });  

  someBtn.addEventListener('touchend', function() { 
    someBtn.backgroundColor ='blue';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works perfectly fine with me. can you try and let me know if it works or not?

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'home',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});
var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    top: 44, 
    left: 5, 
    width: 310, 
    height: 42, 
    backgroundColor: '#333', 
    backgroundSelectedColor: '#fff', 
    backgroundFocusedColor: '#fff', 
    touchEnabled: true, 
    borderWidth: 2, 
    borderRadius: 5
});
win1.add(button1);
win1.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use backgroundSelectedColor:"#colorcode" in the tss.hope it ll work

Answer (score -1):

use backgroundSelectedColor:"color" ,it ll work