# Button not being clicked or blink

Tags: javascript, mobile, button, titanium, event-listener

i am making an event listener of a button in titanium.When i debug the code it is not going to the body of function which i have implemented in listener.Here is the code.

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     backgroundColor:'#ccc',
     title:'Android Cloud Push Notification'
});

var btnSearchcompany = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     backgroundImage : 'images/search.png',
     top : '32%',
     width : '15%',
     height : '5%',
     right : '12%',
     borderRadius : 3
});

win.add(btnSearchcompany);

function searchcompanyyql(){
     alert("wahhab");       
}

btnSearchcompany.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     searchcompanyyql();
});

win.open();
```

Comment: Did you check this [post in this site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709358/titanium-button-not-changing-background-color-when-selected)

Comment: Hi Have you tried this code may there be problem with MyAVD

Comment: Wahhab, I've copied your code and it works well for me. In your case, the click event might not be fired and it might be because your button size is very small and it does not get your touch. Just check it out. And you can directly call the callback function like this
"btnSearchcompany.addEventListener('click', searchcompanyyql);"